# TSQL: Date BETWEEN Query - Ignoring Time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do a query between 2 dates. I would like to do it without having to worry about the time. When a user enters the 2 dates they want to search on, there is no selection for time. This means that the dates that they enter default to 12:00 AM.

The dates in the table do have times though. I just would like to ignore the times all together so the search brings back any records form said date range.

Here is my SQL:

```
TheDate BETWEEN @EnteredBeginDate AND @EnteredEndDate
```

So when a user does a range search between 8/6/2009 AND 9/9/2009 I want to return the records:

```
8/6/2009 11:33:02 AM
8/6/2009 11:39:17 AM
9/9/2009 8:21:30 AM
```

What's happening now is I only get back:

```
8/6/2009 11:33:02 AM
8/6/2009 11:39:17 AM
```

Can someone please recommend the best way to do this in SQL? I know how to do it in C#.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `DATEADD` for the enddate to set it to midnight on the NEXT day...

`TheDate BETWEEN @EnteredBeginDate AND DATEADD(day, 1, @EnteredEndDate)`

If you want to be really precise, you could subtract a second or millisecond from that to make it 11:59:59 on your specified date:

`TheDate BETWEEN @EnteredBeginDate AND DATEADD(second, -1, (DATEADD(day, 1, @EnteredEndDate)))`

Comment: This will be my chosen answer. +1 for the precise option. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you want to be REALLY REALLY precise you could cast to datetime2 and subtract one hundred nanoseconds ;) :)
 `TheDate BETWEEN @EnteredBeginDate AND DATEADD(nanosecond, -100, DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@EnteredEndDate AS datetime2)))`

Answer (score 8):

If you're on SQL Server **2008** or **2008 R2**, you could use the new `DATE` datatype:

```
TheDate BETWEEN CAST(@EnteredBeginDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@EnteredEndDate AS DATE)
```

That strips off the time portion and looks only at the date

Comment: This is great. I have to use 2005 though.

Comment: You need to CAST `TheDate` rather than the Entered Dates. So it should be `CAST(TheDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @EnteredBeginDate AND @EnteredEndDate`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, then do this:

```
TheDate BETWEEN cast(@EnteredBeginDate as date) AND cast(@EnteredEndDate as date)
```

Comment: duplicate of earlier answer by marc_s https://stackoverflow.com/a/8478056/470014

Answer (score 1):

```
TheDate BETWEEN @EnteredBeginDate AND dateadd(day, 1, @EnteredEndDate)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

If just the date is passed into SQL Server, it will make the time 12:00 AM.  So, the end date on the the between clause is 9/9/2009 12:00 AM.  Just add a day or modify the date passed into the query to include the correct time.